# No me ejecuta la instrucción sql

Tags: java

```
package Modelo;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LoginDAO 
{
public void buscarUsuario(String usuario) 


{
    Conexion conex= new Conexion();

    boolean existe=false;
    try {
        Statement estatuto = conex.getConnection().createStatement();
                    String query = "Select username,clave from Logueo where username= '" + usuario+ "'";

        //PreparedStatement consulta = conex.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Logueo  WHERE " + " username = '" + usuario + "'   AND  "  + " clave =  '"+ password+"' ");

        ResultSet res = estatuto.executeQuery(query);



                    while(res.next())

                         //SELECT * FROM Logueo  WHERE  username = '" + usuario + "' " + " AND clave =  '"+ password+"' "
                    {
            existe=true;
                            System.out.println(" "+res.getString("username")+" "+res.getString("clave"));

         }
        res.close();
        conex.desconectar();


        } catch (SQLException e) 
                    {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error, no se conecto");
                System.out.println(e);
        }

        if (existe)
                    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usuario ya se encuentra registrado");
        }

                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usuario No se encuentra registrado");
                    }

}
```

}

Comment: tengo una tabla llamada Logueo  tengo u método para buscar un usuario que recibe un parámetro  y luego tomo el parámetro para ejecutar el sql pero no me ejecuta nada

Comment: La descripción es... confusa. Si no se ejecuta será porque no se invoca, así que el error estaría en otra parte. Si se ejecuta en parte/lanza un error, deberías identificar en qué punto se para y qué error lanza (depurador / System.out.println)

Comment: estoy intentando que  me muestre lo que devuelve el bloque while ,se supone que al ejecutar la consulta debe traerme el contenido de las dos columnas  y no lo esta haciendo

Comment: Deberías editar la pregunta y agregar toda la información necesaria para poder ayudarte, como por ejemplo... una descripción clara y concisa del problema, del entorno, etc..

Comment: creo un objeto Statement estatuto  y  conecto con mi base de datos; luego declaro un string query con mi sentencia ,luego construyo un objeto  ResultSet donde ejecuta la consulta para luego recorrer la tabla con la condición while ,pero por alguna razón salta el bloque  while no ingresa y no me muestra lo que devuelve el query.

Comment: ¿En cuál de estos niveles encuentras el problema? Tu programa debe contemplar el manejo de todas estas situaciones: 1. No se está conectando a la base de datos; 2. Se conecta a la BD pero la instrucción SQL es errónea; 3. La instrucción SQL es correcta pero no está devolviendo datos porque ninguna fila cumple con el criterio; 4. Todo es correcto y hay datos que cumplen el criterio pero no se muestran (seguro que existen esos datos con ese criterio, lo he probado en el manejador de BD directamente) **¿Del 1 al 4, dónde estás encontrando el problema?**

Comment: la 3 envió un parámetro para probar y no devuelve nada y la instrucción sql esta correcta.

Comment: De hecho hice la prueba poniendo el "SELECT * FROM Logueo" y si me devuelve datos pero al poner  la que estoy  intentando  con la otra consulta para  recuperar algunos registros: la sigueinte es la instruccion que estoy  escribiendo:" Select username,clave from Logueo where username= '" + usuario+ "' "

Comment: ¿Y si es la 3, no sale esto en tu OptionPane: `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "usuario No se encuentra registrado");`?

Comment: perdóname es la opción 4 y si he probado la sentencia directamente el el gestor de la Base de Datos y funciona correctamente devolviendo me los registros segun el criterio

Comment: Bien si es la 4, para depurar, sólo como prueba: 1. Escribe una consulta directa con el dato que estás pasando, ese que te arroja resultados en el manejador de BD. O sea algo así más o menos: `String query = "Select username,clave from Logueo where username= 'El nombre que existe'";` 2. Escribe una salida por consola aquí: `if (existe) { System.out.println("José si existe"); ... `

Comment: Bien ya hice lo que dijiste y  y me ejecuta la consulta directamente  como tu  me indicaste  String query = "Select username,clave from Logueo where username= 'Administrador'"; me devuelve  los registrios  entonces creo que el error esta dentro de la sentencia que estoy tratando de implementar en java

Comment: ¿Pusiste esto: `if (existe) { System.out.println("José si existe");`  dentro del if para probar? Tienes que mirar la salida en la consola claro está. Si todo funciona puede ser que haya un problema con el OptionPane.

Comment: si y funciona perfecto me esta mostrando todo ; creo que es la manera en que  el sql  esta declarado   String query = "Select username,clave from Logueo where username= '" + usuario+ "'"; debe tener un error pero no se en donde.

Comment: puedes hacer un System.out.println( query) y probar ese query en la bd, a ver si devuelve algo? si es asi, tu error esta en cualquier otro lado, no vi que hicieran esa prueba hasta ahora.